# hibernate : one-to-many relationship doesn't create one of tables

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, orm

i'm using hibernate orm , i have 2 tables with one-to-many relation and i can't find out why hibernate doesn't create one of my tables(magazine table).
i'm using hbm2dll to create tables automatically.

Magazine.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="ir.sheentech.school.model.magazine.Magazine" table="magazine">
    <id name="magID"  type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="MAG_ID"></column>
        <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="magName"           column="MAG_NAME"        type="java.lang.String"       not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="desc"              column="DESC"            type="java.lang.String"       ></property>

    <set name="entesharat" table="entesharat" inverse="true" cascade="all">
        <key>
            <column name="MAG_ID" not-null="true"></column>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="ir.sheentech.school.model.magazine.Entesharat"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

Entesharat.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="ir.sheentech.school.model.magazine.Entesharat" table="entesharat">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="ID"></column>
        <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name="name"           column="NAME"           type="java.lang.String"             not-null="true"></property>
    <many-to-one name="magazine"    column="MAG_ID"    class="ir.sheentech.school.model.magazine.Magazine" not-null="true"  >       </many-to-one>
</class>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
</session-factory>
```

Magazine.java

```
public class Magazine {
private Integer magID;
private String magName;
private Set<Entesharat> entesharat = new HashSet<Entesharat>(0);
private String desc;
public Integer getMagID() {
    return magID;
}
public void setMagID(Integer magID) {
    this.magID = magID;
}
public String getMagName() {
    return magName;
}
public void setMagName(String magName) {
    this.magName = magName;
}
public Set<Entesharat> getEntesharat() {
    return entesharat;
}
public void setEntesharat(Set<Entesharat> entesharat) {
    this.entesharat = entesharat;
}
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
```

Entesharat.java

```
public class Entesharat {

private Integer id;
private String name;
private Magazine magazine;


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Magazine getMagazine() {
    return magazine;
}
public void setMagazine(Magazine magazine) {
    this.magazine = magazine;
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you specifying your mapping files?

Comment: in resource folder.
entesharat table is ok but magazine doesn't create
i guess it can be a mysql problem for foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the code below

magazine.hbm.xml

```
<property name="desc"              column="DESC"            type="java.lang.String"       ></property>
```

DESC is a keyword in mysql